# How to enable to show dynamically create column in SharePoint default list view

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, pnp-js

I have created a SharePoint list column using following PNP JS command as below,

```
return pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(this.assessmentHistoryListName).fields.addMultilineText("Favorite", 6, true, false, false, true, { Group: "Custom Columns", Hidden: false });
```

I have added custom property `{Group: "Custom Column", Hidden: false}`

Still I can't see column in my `SharePoint` default list view.

Please refer this screenshot.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWo4W.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use pnp js add the column to the default view in the then function:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("testa").fields.add("testfield", "SP.FieldText", { FieldTypeKind: 3, Group: "My Group" }).then(res=>sp.web.lists.getByTitle("testa").defaultView.fields.add("testfield"));
```

References:
[add column to view](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/views/#add)